# Abbrevs with interstitial capital letters

Tags: abbrev

Whenever I type `YouTrack`, abbrev erroneously corrects it to `Youtrack`. I noticed that in my abbrevs file it has `("youtrack" "youtrack" nil :count 7)`. Why is that there, and how can I get abbrev to correctly capitalize it `YouTrack`?

I'd actually prefer if it corrected `Youtrack` to `YouTrack` but editing the abbrevs file to that affect seems to change nothing about the behavior. The only flag that sounds remotely germane is `abbrev-all-caps`, but that doesn't change the behavior to what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the replacement string from `youtrack` to `YouTrack` with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `edit-abbrev` <kbd>RET</kbd> is working for me.

Afterwards I get `YouTrack` if I type `youtrack`.

Test conditions: `emacs-version`: 26.1 build 2, Emacs called with `emacs -Q`